# wordpress + nginx + django: error too many redirect

Tags: php, django, wordpress, nginx

I have just included wordpress into a project to replace django for the landing page of the website. Up to that point everything server related is working just fine. I am a bit wary to make modification to nginx configuration because I am far from an expert in the domain.

I have tried including wordpress location by disabling what I had before which was from django and it is resulting in `ERROR TOO MANY REDIRECT`

here is the code for `/nginx/sites-enabled/conf.d` that I have:

```
server {
    server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot 
location ^~ / {
        alias /home/ubuntu/var/www/html/wordpress;

        index index.php;
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }

        location ~ /wp-content/uploads/ { expires 30d; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }

            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }
            expires 30d;
        }
    }

}


server {
  if ($host = www.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    listen 80;
    server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    location ^~ / {
        alias /home/ubuntu/var/www/html/wordpress;

        index index.php;
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }

        location ~ /wp-content/uploads/ { expires 30d; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }

            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; }
            expires 30d;
        }
    }


}
```

and here is my wp-config file, I have not add anything to it beside db info:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'dbsite1' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'host' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

I have been investigating for a few hours now but I figure out what is wrong and I am worried I will accidently break something crucial. Wondering if someone can see where i am messing up

Comment: check the url in `wp_config` table of the wordpress.

Comment: Instead of `alias`, try: `root /home/ubuntu/var/www/html/wordpress;`

Comment: Charanjit, I must be doing something wrong because I don't have configurated any URL in wp-config.php. Richart, I have tried with root instead of alias and it does not work still